# How to start a list right after the heading in a redefined proof environment?

Tags: amsthm

I've redefined the proof environment to make the heading boldface by adapting the code from the [amsthm documentation](http://ctan.cs.uu.nl/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) (p. 11). I've literally just deleted `\itshape` and typed `\bfseries` instead, nothing else was changed.

(*Note:* It doesn't even matter whether one changes the italics to boldface, the same problem arises when one copies the provided code from the documentation directly into the document.)

Unfortunately, lists now start on the second line instead of beginning right after the heading. Can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item\relax
    {\bfseries
        #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \lipsum[66]
        \item \lipsum[66]
    \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you change anything but the itshape into bfseries?

Comment: Strange, I cannot test until tomorrow

Comment: Off topic: after the [right answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289757/14757) by @egreg, you could wish to use `\newlength{\@thlabel@width}\newcommand{\thmenumhspace}{\settowidth{\@thlabel@width}{\upshape(i)}\sbox{\@labels}{\unhbox\@labels\hspace{\dimexpr-\leftmargin+\labelsep+\@thlabel@width-\itemindent}}}` and then `\begin{enumerate}\thmenumhspace` to get a better spacing in this case, where the item begins the environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. there should be `[...]` after `\item`, whereas you have `{...}`
2. `\hskip\labelsep` should go inside the optional argument

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
    \pushQED{\qed}%
    \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
    \trivlist
    \item[\hskip\labelsep\bfseries#1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
\popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, the code shown in the documentation is wrong. `:(`

Here is the original definition in `amsthm.sty`

```
\newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
```

You might want to do

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\bfseries}{}{}
```

that would avoid looking up the code.

Comment: That's perfect! Pity it's wrong in the documentation indeed. Pity as well that I don't have the hard TeX background and therefore didn't spot the mistakes you pointed out... :)

Comment: @Jeroen On the other hand, you do have TeX.SE! :)